# SUM SQL multiple tables GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

Hello I can't seem to get this question answered.

[image]

the question is :
3.5 For each horse that has won a prize, list the horse name, horse_id and total prize money won.

have tried:

```
SELECT horse_name, horse.horse_id, SUM(prizemoney) 
FROM horse 
JOIN entry ON entry.horse_id=horse.horse_id 
JOIN prize ON entry.event_id=prize.event_code 
GROUP BY horse_name
```

dont get the right answer

This is my answer:

[image]

This is the teachers answer:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything? What exactly was the problem?

Comment: Gosh, homework question 3.5; You do realize educational institutions scan popular Q/A for answers to homework don't you? Better to try answering it yourself first. `Oh, and by the way most of us won't try to translate a data model image into a usable set of tables.`

Comment: I type this in the QUERY box.

SELECT horse_name, horse.horse_id, SUM(prizemoney)
FROM `horse`
JOIN `entry` ON `entry`.`horse_id`=`horse`.`horse_id`
JOIN `prize` ON `entry`.`event_id`=prize.event_code
GROUP BY horse_name

and I dont get the right answer.

Comment: Please add your query into the question; not as a comment. But good to see you have tried.

Comment: Hello. this is the first time I have used this website.

Comment: You need to include PLACE into your join(s)!  i.e. Make sure only the first placed horse gets the first place prizemoney.

Comment: `Hello. this is the first time I have used this website` Yes, we can sense that and we are trying to advise you on both the question and how best to use the site. Suggest you look at "Help" in the footnote at some point: https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: I don't know what you mean. PLACE is not a table. It is a column in 2 tables.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: is EVENT_ID a table? (but you have used it in the query) why should PLACE be a table? Think about it. There is only ONE first prize in each race. Your existing query does not include that logic....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ignore PLACE in your joins then you will get the wrong answer. Include PLACE in the join logic!

```
SELECT horse_name, horse.horse_id, SUM(prizemoney) 
FROM horse 
JOIN entry ON entry.horse_id=horse.horse_id 
JOIN prize ON entry.event_id=prize.event_code 
          AND entry.place = prize.place
GROUP BY horse_name, horse.horse_id
```

also: include ALL non-aggregating columns in the grouop by clause

Comment: That gave me the correct answer. Thank you very much. Now I have to reverse engineer that and try to learn the HOW and WHY. (teachers at university are so useless)

Comment: Your tutor is probably reading that comment tomorrow before s/he marks your paper

Comment: the teacher doesnt care. this is not graded it is just practice for us to improve. thank you again.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. Regarding the WHY: if you ignore place in the joins every horse would win every prize.  Great for the horse owners but not very realistic. So, by including place in the join logic we ensure only the correct place winner get their correct prize money.